# Global action method in MVC _layout.cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am porting over a WebForms ASP.NET project to MVC and I am not sure of the MVC way to go about something.

In the WebForms project there is a Masterpage with a logout button, it appears at the top right of every page.

```
<div class="userTableElementLogout">
    <asp:Button ID="LogOffButton" runat="server" OnClick="LogOffButton_Clicked" Text="LOG OFF" CausesValidation="false" />
</div>
```

And in the Masterpage codebehind file:

```
protected void LogOffButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Logout logic
}
```

So in my MVC project, _layout.cshtml file, I have this:

```
<div class="userTableElementLogout">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl01$LogOffButton" value="LOG OFF" id="log-off-button">
</div>
```

And I have several controllers with views which use the _layout.cshtml file.

How do I write one method/action which handles the click of that button?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should have your logout button in header.
2. Use jQuery or `Html.ActionLink` to make a link between your button and the controller/action method, here it should be Account/logoff
3. Have a partial view in layout with name `_LoginPartial`, which will have a button or image like

   ```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li id="logOff" class="image-style">
           <img class="lhs" style="max-height: 30px; max-width: 30px;" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/logOut.png")" alt="Logout" title="Logout" />
       </li>
   </ul>
   ```
4. Now you can make it call your logoff method in Account controller using ajax call.
5. create this method in Account controller

   ```
   public ActionResult LogOff() {
       this.AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
       // your logout logic here
       return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
   }
   ```

Better way is using jQuery, it lets you have much customisation.

I am assuming that your Account controller is the place where you put logic of login/logout and Index method is for the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this submit button inside a form tag which will be submitted to one of your action method in which you can execute your code to do the log off logic.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Logoff","Account"))
{
   <div class="userTableElementLogout">
      <input type="submit"  value="LOG OFF" id="log-off-button">
   </div>
}
```

Assuming you have an HttpPost `Logoff` action method in `Account` controller which has the above mentioned logout logic.

If you want, you can also simply keep an `anchor` tag which does a GET request to one of your HttpGet action method (Logoff) as well.